# android - GridView is too laggy

Tags: android, performance, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I use `GridView` in `Fragmnet`, Host actvity inlcudes [SlidingMenu](http://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and My grid Items use simple google now card style. but my gridView is too laggy even i use performance trick for my adapter (recycling and holder pattern).

**My Question:**
Is there another performance tweak? or Do i follow right way for the performance? (GridView and Adapter)

gridView adapter:

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RbtItem> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<RbtItem> data = new ArrayList<RbtItem>();


    public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<RbtItem> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        RbtItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getText());
        holder.imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg);
        return row;

    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageItem;
    }

}
```

gridView item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/nowCardStyleRaw"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_singer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="#FF4444" />

</TextView>
```

fargment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/fragment_rbt_list_grid"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="#e3e3e3"
     android:columnWidth="97dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:paddingRight="5dp"
     android:paddingTop="8dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:verticalSpacing="12dp" >
 </GridView>
```

Comment: You're using setImageResource() which decodes bitmaps on the UI thread. Look into asynchronous image decoding -- it's a fair amount of work but there are open source libraries.

Comment: Actually, given that you're only using a single resource (`R.drawable.bg`), this shouldn't be that much work at all. Load it once as a bitmap into memory and then use that bitmap directly.

Comment: He could do that, but at that point, he may as well just set it as the background of the list item.

Comment: i used thread for loading image... now it is better but still laggy